# Show that if $\pm\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and vice versa.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that if $\pm\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and vice versa.

If $\pm\lambda $  is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $Av=\pm\lambda v\implies v^TA^T=\pm \lambda v^T\implies v^TA^TAv=a^2v^Tv  $

How to show that $a^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ from above?

Conversely $A^TAv=a^2v\implies v^TA^TAv=a^2 v^Tv\implies \langle Av,Av \rangle =a^2\langle v,v\rangle\implies ||Av||=a^2||v||\implies ||Av||=\pm a||v||$

How to show that $Av=\pm av$ from here?
Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean  "singular value of $A^TA$" and not "eigenvalue of $A^TA$"?

Comment: @user; It will be eigen value

Comment: [Singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) are nonnegative

Answer (score 4):

If $\lambda$ is a singular value of $A$, then there are orthonormal vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $Av = \lambda u$ and $A^\top u = \lambda v$. Thus, 
$$
(A^\top A) v = A^\top (A v) = A^\top (\lambda u) = \lambda (A^\top u ) = \lambda (\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v.
$$
Since $||v||=1 \ne 0$, it follows that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ (similarly, $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^\top$). Thus, your statement above is not quite correct as written.

Comment: If $\lambda $ is an eigen value of $A$ how does it imply that $Av=\lambda u,Au=\lambda v$

Comment: The problem statement above is incorrect; the correct assertion is that if $\lambda$ is a [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue for both $A^\top A$ and $AA^\top$.